# Excell or R: writting code to automate filtering of non-osicllatory changes in data.

Tags: r, vba, excel

I am new to coding and need direction to turn my method into code.
In my lab I am working on a time-series project to discover which gene's in a cell naturally change over the organism's cell cycle. I have a tabular data set with numerical values (originally 10 columns, 27,000 rows). To analyze whether a gene is cycling over the data set I divided the values of one time point (or column) by each subsequent time point (or column), and continued that trend across the data set [(the top section of the picture is an example of spread sheet with numerical value at each time-point. The bottom section is an example of what the time-comparisons looked like across the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juAyo.png).
I then imposed an advanced filter with multiple AND / OR criteria that followed the logic (Source Jeeped)

```
WHERE (column A >= 2.0 AND column B <= 0.5)
    OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column C <= 0.5)
    OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column D <= 0.5)
    OR (column A >= 2.0 AND column E <= 0.5)
    (etc ...)
```

From there, I slid the advanced filter across the entire data set[(in the photograph, A on the left -- exanple of the original filter, and B -- the filter sliding across the data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPC1A.png)
The filters produced multiple sheets of genes that fit my criteria. To figure how many unique genes met this criteria I merged Column A (Gene_ID's) of all the sheets and removed duplicates to produce a list of unique gene ID's.
The process took me nearly 3 hours due to the size of each spread sheet (37 columns, 27000 rows before filtering). Can this process be expedited? and if so can someone point me in the right direction or help me create the code to do so?

Thank you for your time, and if you need any clarification please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this in R. I think but a common an easy to think about way is to use the `any` function. This basically takes a series of logical tests and puts an "OR" between each of them, so that if any of them return true then it returns true. You can pass each column to it and then combine it with an AND for the logical test for column a. There are probably other ways to abstract this as well, but this should get you started:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = 1:100,
    b = 1:100,
    c = 51:150,
    d = 101:200,
    value = rep("a", 100)
)

df[ df$a > 2 & any(df$b > 5, df$c > 5, df$d > 5), "value"] <- "Test Passed!"
```

Comment: Thanks Shorpy for replying, when I tried your code on a small sample set nothing happened. my input    `df[ df$a > 2 & any(df$b < .5, df$c < .5, df$d < .5, df$e < .5, df$f < .5, df$g < .5, df$h < .5, df$i < .5, df$j < .5, df$k < .5), "value"] <- "Test Passed!"`.   I guess I am confused, is the test being saved as variable?

Comment: Cool, just out of curiosity how familiar are you with R? Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes, I use R studio. Most of my experience is using R packages. I understand most of what you wrote, only confused about the last part. When the "value" column was added to my data it only showed N/A even when the test was true.

Comment: Sweet, just wanted to make sure my answer was appropriate. Did you get an error or anything? 

Basically what's happening is that you're doing a subset and and assignment. So you say "select the rows which pass this logical test and then assign 'passed' or whatever to the `value` column in only those rows. The result should be a variable which has 'passed' in some rows and whatever the default was in other rows. I'm not sure what's going wrong because the example isn't reproducible. Maybe try making the logical test simpler and then build it up from there?